# Understanding webpack and other module loaders

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a bit confused regarding module loaders Like I am using webpack which load modules as chunks but it is only while developing When the code gets minified it will be a single file for all scripts and css and there how the module loaders work?

Any explanation would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer:

You always have a single file know as the bundle with webpack, but it will generate a source map in development (which make it look like multiple files).

#### Detailed answer:

Web browsers don't natively support [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS).

For example this is not natively supported by browsers:

```
var module = require('./module');
```

[webpack](https://webpack.github.io) is module **bundler** (not loader).

Module bundlers allow you to give them a single file to start form and they will write all the required modules (files) into a single large file know as a bundle.

You can then add a single `<script>` tag to your HTML, which will load the bundle.

The reason you see multiple files in the browsers developer tools is because webpack automatically generates a [source map](https://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/source-mapping) which is usually a JSON file which tells the browser's developer tools how to display the generated bundle as multiple files.

### Tl;dr

This is very different from just using `<script>` in a few ways:

1. You have to use globals (or create a global namespace object) to get a reference to your modules dependencies. An example of this is AngularJS which exposes the `angular` global var, and your module just uses the `angualr` global var without `require()`ing it (specifying where it comes from).
2. You have to manually write individual script **in the correct order** before the `<script>` tag of your module that uses those dependencies. For example you must place the AngularJS `<script>` script tag before your modules `<script>` or else things will not work.
3. If you intend on minifying your code using regualr script tags you will (almost) always end up duplicating the multiple `<script>` tags between your HTML and your minification build script.